# Changing a string literal (connection string) in a program without being able to access the original source

Tags: c#, .net

I need to change the connection string that is hard-coded in a single class for a program I created. I no longer have the original source code for the program in question, but I have decompiled it and have access to that.

I've tried re-compiling the decompiled source, but run into issues with the decompiled code being slightly different and requiring numerous changes. I've also tried recreating the class as a DLL without success. I think either of these approaches could work, but there is something I'm missing. Can anyone point me in the right direction, or suggest something simpler that I'm not thinking of?

Comment: Can you subclass the necessary pieces?

Comment: Did you try using ildasm/ilasm ?  These are more likely to work than a C# decompiler.

Comment: can you post some decompiled code of the class with the connection string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your corrected connection string is the same size or shorter than the old one, you should be able to edit the bytecode directly in a hex editor and overwrite the string with your new one. Just remember to change the string length and add `00 00` at the end:

> In the .NET CLR, strings are laid out in memory pretty much the same way that BSTRs were implemented in OLE Automation: as a word-aligned memory buffer consisting of a four-byte integer giving the length of the string, followed by the characters of the string in two-byte chunks of UTF-16 data, followed by two zero bytes.

Comment: Won't that change the hash-code and prevent the runtime from loading it?

Comment: This worked, and the string was easily found in the hex. Thanks!